# Where should I implement general functionality in Polymer?

Tags: javascript, polymer, web-component

I want to implement general functionality (like scrollTo, style calculations, etc..) but not sure how to do it with Polymer.

I'm thinking of implementing it as a behavior, what do you think?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think if it works in a behavior it's the right place.
Here are a list of things that the Polymer team implemented as behavior
https://elements.polymer-project.org/browse?q=behavior
resizable, fit, overlay, sounds similar to your examples to me.